# how to send part of char array with write() socket programming

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

Could someone tell me a way to send only part of a char array over TCP using write()? I want to send the first 255 bytes and then as another block of data send the next 255 bytes and so on/left over instead of the entire data variable such as:

```
 n = write(newsockfd,data,strlen(data));
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Replace `strlen(data)` with `255`?

Comment: I was thinking about that, i guess i don't understand write() well enough. If i do 255 it will read the first 255 bytes but what if i want to then send the next 255 bytes of the char array after that? I'm trying to send data in blocks instead of one entire thing.

Comment: You then need to keep repeating until you have < 255 bytes left. in which case you then send what remains. This will involve keep track of  how much of your data buffer has been sent and progress through the buffer accordingly. I guess this is homework?

Comment: I found that this book was a good introduction: http://man7.org/tlpi/  hope that helps.

Comment: So is there some type of pointer/counter that keeps track of where the write left off for some specific data that we are reading from(in this case the data variable). I was under the impression if we repeated the same thing it would just read the same 255 bytes.

Comment: You need to use a pointer, the starting length and the return value from `write()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int len = strlen(data);
for (int i = 0; i < len; )
{
    n = write(newsockfd, &data[i], min(len-i, 255));
    if (n < 0) {
        // error, do something ...
        break;
    } 
    i += n;
}
```

Or:

```
char *ptr = data;
int len = strlen(data);

while (len > 0)
{
    n = write(newsockfd, ptr, min(len, 255));
    if (n < 0) {
        // error, do something ...
        break;
    } 
    ptr += n
    len -= n;
}
```

Comment: I tried the second batch of code and for some reason it breaks very easily. If my file is more than a couple hundred bytes or i am sending too much at once it stalls after i send and nothing gets received on the client side... really baffled.

Comment: just tested anything more than 94-95 bytes and it does not send anything to the client anymore. What could cause this?

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use send() instead of write()? Are you sure your client is actually reading and acknowledging the data? Have you looked at the network traffic with a packet sniffer, like Wireshark?